# Where could I watch Mallakhamb in India - specifically in/around Delhi?

Tags: sports-events, new-delhi

[Mallakhamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallakhamb) is an Indian sport performed by gymnasts, which I think would be cool to see.

Any ideas as to how one might go about doing so in or around Delhi?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't find extended information about this, the [Aya Nagar Akhada](http://wikimapia.org/4588303/Akhada-Wrestling-Ground) (*akhada* means "wrestling ground") does have students who learn this sport. This is a fairly rustic area so I don't think you'll be able to contact them over the phone, but the best course of action would be to just go there and see when / if they have a session going on.